# CompletableFuture along with reading using FileReader, the program doesn't exit

Tags: java, file, asynchronous, completable-future

**Backgroud**

Building a data pipeline where each message received is to be processes asynchronously.
Trying to simulate the behavior by

- Reading message from file
- Processing with CompletableFuture

**Code**

```
 BufferedReader reader = null;
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
 try {
   String filepath = str[0];
   FileReaderAsync fileReaderAsync = new FileReaderAsync();
   reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
   Random r = new Random();
   String line; 
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          Integer val = Integer.valueOf(line.trim());
          int randomInt = r.nextInt(5);
          Thread.sleep(randomInt * 100);
          CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
              System.out.println("Square : " + val);
              return val * val;
          }, service) 
             .thenApplyAsync(value -> {
                  System.out.println(":::::::Double : " + value);
                  return 2 * value;
              }, service)
              .thenAccept(value -> {
                   System.out.println("Answer : " + value);
              });
   }
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     try {
          reader.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

For simplicity just pasting main method code, assume variables are declared and in scope.

**Issues**

*Code*

- Program works fine but does not exit, tried commenting Async logic and just reading the file. it works fine and ends too.

*Design*

- In Streaming pipeline, will this Async model work for each incoming message if each message is passed to the CompletableFuture for processing?
- Or it will block for current message to be processed ?
- It is required to introduce another queue and then consume from it instead of consuming incoming messages as they flow in ?

**Edit 1**
Added

```
public void shutdown() {
   service.shutdown();
}
```

and

```
  reader.close();
  fileReaderAsync.shutdown();
```

which did the trick.

Comment: What is `service`? Does it use _non-daemon_ threads?

Comment: edited the question to include `service` definition which is a threadpool. No idea about thread type.

Comment: That factory method returns a thread pool that, by default, uses _non-daemon_ threads. As long as there's one _non-daemon_ thread alive the JVM will remain alive (unless you kill the process or call `exit`, of course). Not sure what exact solution would work for you, but you basically need to make sure the threads are either _daemon_ (using a `ThreadFactory`), or you need to `shutdown()` the pool when finished with it.

Comment: Fair enough, Added `Edit 1` in above description and it worked. But in streaming pipeline perspective, which will run over few months ( at least), how should one use service like this ? or a simple thread is the option ?

Comment: I don't believe I have the necessary experience to advise you there. Perhaps you should look for an existing library that provides what you need. Or at least that you can take inspiration from, if you can't find someone else that can tell you what should be done.

Comment: Yes, working in that direction too. Would you please kindly move your comment to Answer for me to accept ? as it worked for me after adding a call to `shutdown()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

You're using a thread pool created by:

```java
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

Which by default is configured to use *non-daemon* threads. And as documented by [java.lang.Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html):

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named `main` of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The `exit` method of class `Runtime` has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the `run` method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the `run` method.

In other words, any *non-daemon* thread that is still alive will also keep the JVM alive.

---

## Solution

There are at least two solutions to your problem.

### Shutdown the Thread Pool

You can shutdown the thread pool when you're finished with it.

```java
service.shutdown(); // Calls ExecutorService#shutdown()
```

The `#shutdown()` method starts a graceful shutdown. It prevents any new tasks from being submitted but allows any already-submitted tasks to complete. Once all tasks are complete the pool will terminate (i.e. all threads will be allowed to die). If you want to wait for all tasks to complete before continuing then you can call `#awaitTermination(long,TimeUnit)` after calling `#shutdown()` / `#shutdownNow()`.

If you want to try and immediately shutdown the pool then call `#shutdownNow()`. Any currently-executing tasks will be cancelled and any submitted-but-not-yet-started tasks are simply not executed (and are in fact returned to you in a list). Note whether a task responds to cancellation depends on how that task was implemented.

### Use Daemon Threads

A *daemon* thread will not keep the JVM alive. You can configure the thread pool to use *daemon* threads via a `ThreadFactory`.

```java
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4, r -> {
  Thread t = new Thread(r); // may want to name the threads
  t.setDaemon(true);
  return t;
});
```

Note you should still shutdown the thread pool when finished with it, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 threads in the pool but the Thread.sleep() will block the main thread. Your program reads a line, blocks for max. 5 secs, will then fire the async code which does not require any async-ness at all and will in fact creates a huge overhead.

Do not use Thread.sleep() in an async program.

But I tried to get the idea of your code and I can offer this:

```
public int calcWork(final int x) {
    return x*x;
}

public void iter_async_rec(final BufferedReader reader) {
    String line = reader.readline();
    if (line != null) {     
         int i = Integer.tryParse(line); // checks required       
         CompetableFuture.supplyAsync(calcWork(i))
         .thenSupplyAsync(i->System.out.println(i))
         .thenRunAsync(()->iter_asnc_rec(reader))
    }
}
```

In addition: Most of the time it is the best choice to just use the standard executors. The given sample will not improve speed, on the contrary.

Maybe have a look at the reactive idea!? [reactivejava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Comment: Well, call to `sleep` is for simulating messages coming at some random interval. it can be removed as well which in fact I did. My mistake if it led to any confusion.