# Async Operation in A Flink Sink using CompletableFuture

Tags: asynchronous, apache-flink, flink-streaming

**Background**

Planning to set a up data pipeline using Flink.

The flow looks like this

```
        Kafka --> Flink Job --> gRPC endpoint
```

**Story so far**

1. Blocking implementation is up and running. But that will not scale for high QPS
2. Tried simulating async behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68551919/completablefuture-along-with-reading-using-filereader-the-program-doesnt-exit)

**Problem**

- For Async Behavior not sure how the behavior would be
- if `CompletableFuture` is used, per message it will be processed in `Async` manner, but will the next message be fetched for processing before processing of first is complete ? In other words, there is a way to achieve async processing within a task manager. But what is the behavior of Task manager in fetching next message / tuple ? Will is wait till `Async` process is complete or will it submit to CompletableFuture / Thread and fetch next message ? Not clear about that
- Will using a custom threadpool cause any issues if not `shutdown` as the pipeline will be running over a long period ?
- Any other solution to achieve async behavior in Flink sink ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "... but will the message will be processed before processing of first is complete". Are you asking whether messages will be processed in the exact order in which they arrive? If so, the answer is no, as once you parallelize async operations (in any system, not just Flink) there's no guarantee about completion order.

Comment: My bad, corrected my question. It is about submitting say current message for processing and fetching next one before it has completed processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage Flink's support for async operators, and have a `DiscardingSink`, versus trying to implement a custom async sink.

And no, I don't see any reason why having a persistent thread pool would cause problems.